# How to read and run procedure from argument in Scheme?

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, scheme, procedure

is it possible to give procedure definition as an argument and then somehow run it in the program? For example if I call `(program 'write-hello '((procedure write-hello ('Hello.))))` . How can I read the procedure from argument? I spent few hours on it and can't really find any solution to it as I'm new to Scheme. 
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you expect this code to do?  Or be able to do after it is run?

Comment: I would have a function `(define program (expresion procedure) (eval expresion (some-environment)))` and it would evaluate the given procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are *first class citizens* in Scheme: they are values that can be passed just like the more traditional data types, and the parameter name can be used as if there were a function with that name defined in the traditional way.

If you have defined a function in the normal way (using `define`), then you can just pass the name.  But you can also make a function *object* using `lambda`, which can be used like any other value (bound to names, passed as an argument) in addition to its function-like abilities (i.e. applied to arguments).

The following are equivalent:

```
(define (plus a b) (+ a b))
(define plus_a (lambda (a b) (+ a b)))
```

And if you have the following (notice how `op` is being used):

```
(define (do_op op a b) (op a b))
```

Then these would also be equivalent to each other:

```
(do_op + 5 6)
(do_op plus 5 6)
(do_op plus_a 5 6)
(do_op (lambda (a b) (+ a b)) 5 6)
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly I should be able to do something like `(define (procedure_parameter_name rest_of the parameter)`? I'm just not sure how to make it findable for the evaluating expression.

Answer (score 0):

For Scheme you just pass the lambda definition like `(lambda (n) (* n n))` eg.

```
(define (display-result procedure value)
  (display (procedure value))

(display-result (lambda (n) (* n n)) 5) ; displays 25
```

If a procedure is bound to a name, like `+` or defined with `define` you just use that name in place of the lambda expression.

If you are after making an interpreter of some language then you need to implement this feature yourself by managing your own environment. It's not simple and if you're a newbie it will take more than hours to complete. I recomment watching the [SICP videos](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/).

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the videos, Scheme is quite hard to learn. I tried playing around with the lambda function but I can't make it run. The function just isn't capable of being accessible. I guess I'll do some deeper study before I try doing it again.

Comment: @missInTrouble: Scheme is *easy* to learn with [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), but you'll need a *fresh* mindset